# Toggle view of DIVs using javascript array and radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to toggle the visibility to div content using javascript, not jquery.  I can get it to work using a huge else if, but I am trying to use a for loop.

HTML

```
<fieldset >
  <legend>Please indicate below how you intend to pay any pick-related charges for you shipments.</legend>
  <div >
    <input id="repl_id"  name="repl_name" type="radio" value="111">
    <label for="repl_id" >Bill to your Account Number.</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <input id="repl_id"  name="repl_name" type="radio" value="222">
    <label for="repl_id" >Bill to a paymentcard.</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <input id="repl_id"  name="repl_name" type="radio" value="333">
    <label for="repl_id" >Bill to the reciever or a third party.</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <input id="repl_id"  name="repl_name" type="radio" value="444">
    <label for="repl_id" >Pay with check or money order.</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <input id="repl_id"  name="repl_name" type="radio" value="555">
    <label for="repl_id" >Pay with cash.</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div id="111"><p>This is 111</p></div>
<div id="222"><p>This is 222</p></div>
<div id="333"><p>This is 333</p></div>
<div id="444"><p>This is 444</p></div>
<div id="555"><p>This is 555</p></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(":input[type='radio']").on("change", function () {
  var choice =[111,222,333,444,555];
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    for(i=0; i<=choice.length; i++){
      if($(this).val() === choice[i]){
        $("#"+i).show();
      } else {
        $("#"+i).hide();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that it does not seem to recognize the index of the array I am iterating through. So it always reads false.  No JQuery please.

Comment: This is actually jQuery :P

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. If you need to duplicate, use classes.

Comment: have you tried using typeless comparitor instead? == instead of === ? maybe the types are different somehow.

Comment: I would answer, but it needs more jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/of3gm5h8/1/

HTML

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Please indicate below how you intend to pay any pick-related charges for you shipments.</legend>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="111">
    <label for="repl_id">Bill to your Account Number.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="222">
    <label for="repl_id">Bill to a paymentcard.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="333">
    <label for="repl_id">Bill to the reciever or a third party.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="444">
    <label for="repl_id">Pay with check or money order.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="555">
    <label for="repl_id">Pay with cash.</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div id="111" class="hide">
  <p>This is 111</p>
</div>
<div id="222" class="hide">
  <p>This is 222</p>
</div>
<div id="333" class="hide">
  <p>This is 333</p>
</div>
<div id="444" class="hide">
  <p>This is 444</p>
</div>
<div id="555" class="hide">
  <p>This is 555</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();

  $("input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
    // Hide all the .hide divs
    $('.hide').hide();
    var checked = $(this).val();

    if (checked == "111") {
      $("#111").show();
    } else if (checked == "222") {
      $("#222").show();
    } else if (checked == "333") {
      $("#333").show();
    } else if (checked == "444") {
      $("#444").show();
    } else if (checked == "555") {
      $("#555").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You win. I do not have the rep to thums-up you, but this works thanks you.

Comment: I found another problem.  Your solution works great on jsfiddle, but has no effect in my page.  I assume I'm doing that wrong.  I have the js inside <head><script>... js content ...</script></head>

Comment: Make sure to include jquery library on very top of `<head>` section before above JS script.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the id's of the radio buttons are unique.(You already have the same name for the radio button to make it behave like a group.)

Then target the div using the value of the radio button.

**JS**

```
$(":input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
  // Hide all the divs
  $('.div-container div').hide();
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Please indicate below how you intend to pay any pick-related charges for you shipments.</legend>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id1" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="111">
    <label for="repl_id1">Bill to your Account Number.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id2" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="222">
    <label for="repl_id2">Bill to a paymentcard.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id3" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="333">
    <label for="repl_id3">Bill to the reciever or a third party.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id4" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="444">
    <label for="repl_id4">Pay with check or money order.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="repl_id5" name="repl_name" type="radio" value="555">
    <label for="repl_id5">Pay with cash.</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="div-container">

  <div id="111">
    <p>This is 111</p>
  </div>
  <div id="222">
    <p>This is 222</p>
  </div>
  <div id="333">
    <p>This is 333</p>
  </div>
  <div id="444">
    <p>This is 444</p>
  </div>
  <div id="555">
    <p>This is 555</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysgzepm2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
//removed the colon before input
$("input[type='radio']").on("change", function () {
  var choice =[111,222,333,444,555];
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    //get the value of the checked input
    var value = $(this).val();
    //match the index to the input and show it, hide the others.
    $('#'+value).show().siblings().hide();
  }
}
```

This assumes that the choice array has all the values from the the inputs.

Comment: Didn't see the divs below the inputs however note that ids shouldn't start with numbers.